# The mirrored character does not animate properly in Blender

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

I made character in Blender, using the "mirror" modifier in such parts as feet or arms. [Character at the Edit mode here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waDYh.png)
So, here's the problem. After creating bones, connecting the character and the bones, and trying to change pose at Pose mode, everything is breaking apart. [For instance, after reposition of one arm another arm is going crazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Ykp.png)

[And after reposition of only one leg another one is changing position as the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeIJx.png)

Tried to search information everywhere, but it was in vain. Hope anybody helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was complete beginner. The answer is simple as the question is dumb. I used mirror modifier, and before rigging the character you must apply the modifier.